# Location CNI plugin configuration(s) of the Docker Desktop with WSL2 network infrastructure?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, docker-desktop, cni

Investigating Docker Desktop on Windows with WSL2 using the [Edgeshark](https://github.com/siemens/edgeshark) open source tool, I get the following network topology for the container workload:

[image: Deocker Desktop with WSL2 network topology]

Please note how this is a Docker-in-containerd setup, so the Docker engine lives inside a containerd container, in the `services.linuxkit` namespace of containerd.

Now I "suspect" that Docker Desktop might use CNI plugins with containerd to network its managed containers, such as the `docker1`-`eth0` and `services1` -`eth0` VETH "networks". If this actually is the case, where can I find the CNI plugin configuration for this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, we need a way to look into the environment around the Docker engine, and a way to see it, is to deploy an inspection container as follows:

```bash
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid host alpine
```

Next, we can look around via the wormhole of `/proc/1/root/`; this turns up a directory `/proc/1/root/containers` with an `onboot` sub-directory. There's more here:

- `/proc/1/root/containers`

  - `onboot`

    - ...
    - `004-docker-net`
    - `005-docker-net-root`
    - ...
  - `services`

    - ...

`004-docker-net/runtime.json` contains a "section" about (network) interfaces:

```json
    "interfaces": [
        {
            "name": "docker0",
            "add": "veth",
            "peer": "docker1",
            "createInRoot": false
        }
    ],
```

So, there is no "traditional" CNI plugin configuration used here, but Docker Desktop does its own thing.